# SOLR - query only specific fields

Tags: solr

I have a search index consisting of a number of fields, that is supposed to be used from multiple applications. For instance, say I have the following fields:

- A
- B
- C
- D
- E

Values to fields, A, B, C are supplied from ApplicationX, while values to fields  D and E are supplied from ApplicationY. When conducting searches from ApplicationX, I would like to get results from hits on fields A,B,C, and when I search from ApplicationY I would like hits from B,C,D,E.

I have tried something like this, where `str` is a variable holding my search string:

```
A:(str) B:(str) C:(str)
```

The problem with this is when inputing a search string like `A:monkey`, I get

```
A:(A:monkey) B:(A:monkey) C:(A:Monkey)
```

instead of just `A:monkey`.

Is there a way to query SOLR so that it only returns hits from specific fields, and at the same time keep the possibility of writing SOLR-syntax queries in my applications?

Comment: Can you show the raw query that is being sent to Solr for that example search?

Comment: If you are already providing the field in `str` variable like `A:monkey` then why are you replacing it in `A:(str) B:(str) C:(str)`?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use edismax and use `qf`, specific field names in the query should override the ones provided in `qf`.

For queries regarding App1, specify `qf=A B C`, while for App2 specify `qf=B C D E`. If you submit a query against a specific field (i.e. `A:monkey`), the qf parameter will be ignored.